# error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function CV2 Error

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, vision

I am making a program in python that just draws a rectangle around a car. I am currently stuck on getting the coordinates of the car, here is the code:

```
#################################################
import cv2
#################################################
car_data = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "cars.xml")
img = cv2.imread("car_front.jpeg")
#################################################
img_but_bnw = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

car_coordinates = car_data.detectMultiScale(img_but_bnw)
print(car_coordinates)

#################################################
cv2.imshow("Detect Everything", img_but_bnw)
cv2.waitKey()
print("Code Completed")
#################################################
```

I am running in on an error with the function "cv2.detectMultiScale".
error:

```
File "e:\Python2\Body_Detection.py", line 11, in <module>
    car_coordinates = car_data.detectMultiScale(img_but_bnw)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'
```

I have tried googling, it says to use `cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "cars.xml")` instead of `cv2.CascadeClassifier("cars.xml")`. It didn't work :(, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this is being asked every other day. please use the search function.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: OpenCV doesn't raise error when it can't read file but later it show problem when you try to use files. You should first check if you get data from `.xml` and from `.jpg` because they can be empty. ie. image may need to use `/full/path/to/image.jpg`. You could also check if `cv2.data.haarcascades + "cars.xml"` really exists on disk. See `print( os.listdir(cv2.data.haarcascades) )`

Comment: I checked `print( os.listdir(cv2.data.haarcascades) )` on my computer and there is NO `cars.xml`. If it is your file then better use `/full/path/to.cars.xml` because code may run from different folder and it may not find this file in your folder.

Comment: Your code is working If I used this cv2.CascadeClassifier("cars.xml"). But in ur case the filename is not in currently directory or probably misspelled filename or extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `cars.xml` is not part of the `opencv` library although you may find tutorials in the internet that use this filename. The folder addressed by `cv2.data.haarcascades` includes xml examples for things like eye and face detection (current content see https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data).

You can search for an existing `cars.xml` example by other authors and copy it to your project folder. Then just use `"cars.xml"` without `cv2.data.haarcascades`.

E.g. I found this project [Vehicle Detection with Haar Cascades](https://github.com/andrewssobral/vehicle_detection_haarcascades) that includes a file `cars.xml` working fine with your code above.

Comment: yeah so, it was just my stupid brain. the "cars.xml" file didn't actually have XML code in it...

it had like ``` <script src="https://gist.github.com/199995/37e1e0af2bf8965e8058a9dfa3285bc6.js"></script> ```